# WKWebView - Add a parameter to the URL on redirect in Swift - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, redirect, wkwebview

I am new to Swift, currently using swift 4.0 and have a very simple app with WKWebView loading a web page.

I have a requirement to append a parameter to a URL when page redirects from one page to another.

I am getting the redirection event in this function:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {

}
```

But here I am not sure how to update the URL by adding a parameter to it and then do the navigation. Please help in this regard to update the URL before navigating.

I have searched for it and tried to figure out the way to do it but so far I haven't progressed. The `navigationAction.action.url` is GET only and I am not able to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WKNavigationDelegate, URLComponents

```
class ViewerViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate  //<--
// then whenever you call the WKWebView
//ex: URL = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page

WKWebView.navigationDelegate = self


WKWebView.load(URLRequest)


func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {




    print("URL:", navigationAction.request.url)
    if let host = navigationAction.request.url?.path 
     {
         if host.contains("Main_Page")
          {
              //You can modify this part to form a new url and pass it again.
              var components = URLComponents()
              components.scheme = navigationAction.request.url?.scheme
              components.host =  navigationAction.request.url?.host
              components.path =  navigationAction.request.url!.path 
                        
             print("new URL:", components.url!)
             let customRequest = URLRequest(url: components.url!)

             //change the url and pass it again..
             WKWebView.load(customRequest) //<--load the new url again..
             decisionHandler(.cancel) 
        }
        else
        {
             decisionHandler(.allow) //<-- this will open the page.
        }
     }
     else
     {
         decisionHandler(.allow)
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will check and will update how it goes

Comment: Thanks that helped. I have updating the last bit of your code to pass the updated URL properly, after that it worked.